# Why Azure DevOps API doesn't allow to select application permissions for an AAD application?

Tags: api, permissions, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I need to access Azure DevOps API from a python script.
So, I registered an application in Azure active directory and I have to assign some API permissions(application/delegated) to the application.

But in the Request API permissions section, the **application permissions** is disabled. I am able to assign **delegated permissions** only.

Why it is so? Is it a case that Azure DevOps services and it's REST API can only be accessed as a specific signed-in user? Could it be accessed as an application itself (ie, without a user) as Microsoft Graph API allows?

Comment: I think you can't, azure devops api does not support the application permission.

Comment: Okay. Can I use the delegated permissions effectively? I mean is it possible to use that AAD application to authenticate with Azure DevOps REST API?